Fork FirebaseUI-Android from Github and customise FirebaseUI
Trying to customise the firebase-ui in the FirebaseUI-Android source by forking a release 1.0.0 here
In my build.gradle (:app) file I've added
implementation 'com.github.daveinaus:FirebaseUI-Android:firebase-ui-auth:1.0.0'
however getting Failed to resolve: com.github.daveinaus:FirebaseUI-Android:firebase-ui-auth when syncing the gradle file.
I've done this before with the the example from jetpack.io 
This works
implementation 'com.github.daveinaus:android-example:1.0.0'

Turns out the FirebaseUI-Android repo is failing to build on jetpack.io over here https://jitpack.io/com/github/DaveInAus/FirebaseUI-Android/1.0.0/build.log. Anybody done something similar?
